# Could we teach an AI to code better than people?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, computers

Neural Networks are often used to divise efficent ways of accomplishing tasks. We switched to higher levels of code because the additional levels of abstraction meant it was easier for people do code, at the cost of computational efficency.

**Would it be possible to use a neural network to create programs in lower level code or even binary in order to increase computational efficency? How complicated would this look? Is there a better way of making an AI that codes?**

You can learn about neural networks here:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network

Comment: There is an interesting nuance in how this question is worded, with regard to how neural networks operate. "Could _we_ teach?" or "Can the AI learn?"

Comment: @Alexander the reason I say we is because the humans have to set up the neural net system with the parameters to learn. So the question becomes if we could set up the system correctly in the first place for such a thing to occur

Comment: I assume that by "computational efficiency" you mean the time and / or space complexity of a program. The complexity of an algorithm is exactly the same (up to a constant factor) regardless of the programming language. Programming 101: focus on the algorithms, and let the compiler bother with micro-optimizations. For any reasonably modern processor the compiler is actually *much better* at micro-optimizations that any human. And, fundamentally, in order to write code one must first understand the problem; at present we don't know how to make such a machine.

Comment: Can you make clear why you think this is a Worldbuilding question and not a Computer Science question?

Comment: I also don't see how this is worldbuilding. The answer is also a fairly boring "yes, definitely, but not yet"

Comment: L.Dutch because I'm looking for more of a broad brush based on a what if rather than raw technical explanations. If I asked on CompSci I feel like the answers would either go right over my head or shut me down entirely. Worldbuilding is much more open to fantastic hypotheticals I think. It could either way though.

Comment: Worldbuilding is _not_ open to any "fantastical hypothetical". This is not a "What if?" site. We are a collaborative community dedicated to Building Worlds (come on, it's in the name!)

Comment: For the moment, ignore "neural networks," which defined simply is merely a way of helping a logic analyzer learn from its mistakes.  If we ask, "can a computer be taught to write code better than a human?" the answer is no, since there is as much art (imagination) in code as there is logic.  If you ask, "can a computer do it more efficiently?" the answer is possibly yes, but now we're talking about "intelligent" compilers.  It is worth noting that at this time and in the near future, no computer can be smarter than its creator, more efficient, but not smarter.

Comment: Also, what makes you think a C compiler results in inefficient machine code?  You talk as if, somehow, binary/machine code (in my day called "assembly language") is no longer part of the process.  I assure you, it is the end result of the process, and while programmers can create inefficient software, I'm not convinced that todays compilers inherently create inefficient binary.  It's like saying hammers are inefficient because contractors ask subcontractors to do a job and the subcontractor hires an apprentice who doesn't know how to use a hammer.

Comment: More abstraction doesn't necessarily mean less efficiency. There are great strides being made to make heavily abstracted languages much more efficient

Answer (score 5):

First off, if we drop the big about neural networks, we already do exactly as you say.  We have software which takes high level instructions and generates highly optimized low level code (all the way down to the binary machine code) which humans could never possibly do on their own.  On modern large projects, it is simply unreasonable for a human hand to write all that machine language code at the same level of speed a modern compiler can.

So what changes when we add neural networks into the mix?  The first thing that changes is that we no longer have any sort of guarantee that the program we request will actually be what we get.  Neural networks don't offer that kind of guarantee, and they are never designed to offer that guarantee.  They're designed to learn and find the patterns you didn't think to tell them about.  If you only ever use a neural network to do what you told it to do, you're wasting everyone's time.

So what you're looking for is not just some technology.  You're looking for us to *desire* the development of software to fuzzy standards.  There needs to be value in providing an incomplete story of the software we want to see, rather than providing a complete one.  Find a reason for *why* we would want this sort of technology, and it will appear.

One possible reason: unique user experiences.  If each user wants a slightly customized experience, they may want their device to learn their habits.  Maybe one user has a slight twitch which causes some single-taps to become double-taps, so they want double-taps to be a bit harder to accidentally do.  To program to this environment means programming to ten-thousand environments.  That's hard to do, and very fuzzy.  A neural network may be able to take your code (written in some high level form) and information about how the user wants the program to act (gathered by their own neural network), and custom write an application for that user and their UI style.

Of course, you may already have a fuzzy task in mind.  In FPGA design, there is a notoriously nebulous step called "routing" where the compiler figures out where to put elements on the chip.  This process is [already being explored](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7406595/) as a candidate for neural networks.  So, in that sense, your question of "is it possible" can indeed be answered with "yes, it is possible, and we do it already."

Comment: FPGAs are some of the coolest voodoo ever created by man.  And the reason the routing would benefit from neural network learning is that it must be 100% automated.  All chips are "routed" during the design process, but it's a human-controlled process - and despite its automation, it's still very much an art form.  It's an ultra complex combination of maze and jigsaw puzzle that sometimes only human intuition can overcome.  Once it can be 100% automated, it'll be blow-your-mind cool voodoo.  Would that I might live to see the day.

Comment: +several thousand for "if you only ever use a neural network to do what you told it to do, you're wasting everyone's time" please explain this to my AI crazy boss

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and AI is already doing it.

The is already a number of code analysis tools that check the code for potential errors and unoptimized lines, and suggest corrections. As of today, these tools are better than humans at spotting all the potential problems, but not always good at suggesting improvements. They sure can get better, but we need to take a look at software development process as a whole.

Generally we can divide writing a program into at least 3 phases:

1. Requirements
2. Design
3. Implementation

Your question is focused on phase #3 (implementation), but it cannot be solved alone without phases 1&2 completed and formalized. If AI has to write the code while making guesses about the exact purpose of our program, we can't expect good results. AI can be good at playing games like chess, because there are formalized rules and goals. If there is no formalized goal, AI as of today can not help.

So, there are some possible solutions as to how we can better engage the AI.

1. Make requirements and design more formalized. This will give the AI a stable playing field, but keep in mind that most problems with software are due to the flaws in requirements and design, not with the code itself;
2. Let AI handle all the process from very beginning. Today's technology is still too far from it, but I can imagine AI interviewing project stakeholders just like business analysts/project owners do it today.

Comment: While software certainly provides assistance in writing code currently and does virtually all translation from high level code to low level executables (normally via a compiler) it would strain the the definition of AI to call those programs AI. Also, when working with a high level language, the process of formalizing the design is tightly intertwined with the actual coding and in some cases may be indistinguishable.